# macro inside enum c++

Tags: c++, macros

I need to write functions like this:

```
void foo()
{
    //some details
}
enum fun_names
{
    fun_name_foo,
};
```

So I made 2 macros:

```
#define MAKE_FUN(fun) void fun(){}
#define ADD_FUN(fun) fun_name_##fun,
```

Then use them like this:

```
MAKE_FUN(foo)
MAKE_FUN(bar)
enum fun_names
{
    ADD_FUN(foo)
    ADD_FUN(bar)
};
```

But as you can see, I'm repeating 2 macros with exactly same arguments. Is it possible to make one single macro like this?

```
CREATE_FUN(foo)
CREATE_FUN(bar)
```

This saves lines of codes and is less error-prone.

Comment: Why not just name the enum values directly? Is `fun_name_foo` any harder to type than `ADD_FUN(foo)` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, and by doing so, can I  define the function and add it to the enum in just 1 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible trick might be to have a macro taking a macro name as argument

```
#define DO_ENUM(Mac) \
  Mac(foo) \
  Mac(bar)
```

then

```
#define DECLARE_ENUM(X) X,
enum fun_names {
  Nothing,
  DO_ENUM(DECLARE_ENUM)
};
#undef DECLARE_ENUM
```

and to declare the functions:

```
#define DECLARE_FUN(X) void myfun_##X(void);
DO_ENUM(DECLARE_FUN)
#undef DECLARE_FUN
```

and so on.

Another way might be to *generate* some specialized header files, e.g. using some `awk` script, from another file containing the list of functions etc..

Comment: Define an enum-macro to enum other macros? Nice trick! hmm... and I have to add new functions inside the `DO_ENUM` macro, which must be put before `DECLARE_ENUM` and `DECLARE_FUN`? This might be a problem... And `DECLARE_ENUM` `DECLARE_FUN` must be made same format, this is not really a problem though.